# Multiple Open Workbooks combined to one sheet

Tags: vba, list, loops, dynamic

I extract multiple reports daily and they all start with the word "report". They all have the same amount of columns just different amount of rows. What I have created is a sub that will loop through all open workbooks with the name "report" in the beginning and grab the data to put in consecutive order in my master workbook "Distribution"

I have the macro doing exactly what I need it to do but I am looking for guidance to make it more dynamic. The Header row I am copying every time and if a new column is added it wouldn't be captured. Same with the rows.

I am still fairly new to VBA but I think I am starting to understand more and more. Sorry for all the commented sections. Any helpful pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
'Get Data button
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim nrow As Long

    Set wsh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
screen 0 'turns off calculation and screen updating
nrow = 2
    For Each wbk In Workbooks
        If Left(wbk.Name, 6) = "report" Then
            wbk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Copy _ 'copies the header row
                Destination:=wsh.Range("A1") 'paste data in row 1
            wbk.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:Z500").Copy _ 'copy the rest of the
                Destination:=wsh.Range("A" & nrow) 'paste data next available row
            wbk.Close False
            nrow = wsh.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1 'Next row to paste next sheet into
        End If
    Next wbk

nrow = 0 ' reset next row

FilterData 'Function to filter unwanted data
screen 1 'Turn on screen updating and calculation

End Sub
```

Comment: Your best bet is to use Excel tables and transfer the data column by column. You can still do it without using Excel tables, but it will be a bit more work. Can you change your workbooks to be in Excel tables or you have no control on that? Are the headers exactly the same on different workbooks?

Comment: I have no control to change them to tables, Unless I manually do that. Yes, the columns will always be the same as it is the same report different time frame, The reports are pulled in 30 day increments. (IE 0-30, 31-60,61-90). But the rows in each vary.. My main concern is that if the rows exceed 500 or the columns go past Z.

Comment: If all of the columns will be the same and the order will remain the same, then this code will work fine. You can actually copy paste the used range and not limit it to Z column or row 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
'Get Data button
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim nrow As Long

    Set wsh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
screen 0
    For Each wbk In Workbooks
        If Left(wbk.Name, 6) = "report" Then
            wbk.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:Z1").Copy _
                Destination:=wsh.Range("A1")
            nrow = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            wbk.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:Z500").Copy _
                Destination:=wsh.Range("A" & nrow)
            wbk.Close False
        End If
    Next wbk

nrow = 0

FilterData
Sheets("admin").Select
screen 1

End Sub
```